# PHP to Handle API Return instead of print

Tags: api, curl

My API End point has return statement instead of print or echo :
e.g.

```
return json_encode($data);
instead of
print json_encode($data);
```

I have a curl caller to consume my API. When I try to display the result, it shows null. However if I change API End point to :

```
print json_encode($data);
```

I can see the result.

Any idea how can I deal with return statement.

Comment: Why? If `print` (or `echo`) does what you want, why do you want to use `return`?

Comment: I am eager to know how do I deal with return.

Comment: You don't. If you want output you need to use `print` or `echo`. The whole point of return is to *not* do that. return is for passing data between functions/variables.

Comment: Wait, wait... Are you talking about REST API endpoints? If so, then it should return it's value and not print it, I believe... Could you show more of your code?

Comment: Something like below:
Inside routes.php:  

    Router::connect('/api/fetch',   
    array( 'Controller' => 'FetchController',  
    Action' => 'fetch', 'Method' => 'GET' ),  $_GET );  
  
  
Inside Controller:  

    public function fetch( $DATA )  
    {  
    echo "100"; //works  
    #return 100; //doesn't  
    }